# Cannot install using Composer

Tags: git, composer-php, installation

I am attempting to install the GitHub bandwidth-throttle, but run into Composer error.

1. Via FTP, I created a directory called 'bandwidth'.
2. Via SSH, I ran cloned:

   ```sh
   git clone https://github.com/bandwidth-throttle/bandwidth-throttle
   ```
3. Via SSH, I attempted to install by executing the following inside the newly created bandwidth/bandwidth-throttle directory:

   ```sh
   composer require bandwidth-throttle/bandwidth-throttle
   ```

This was the result (Composer error):

```sh
Using version ^0.1.0 for bandwidth-throttle/bandwidth-throttle
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Installation request for bandwidth-throttle/bandwidth-throttle ^0.1.0 -> satisfiable by bandwidth-throttle/bandwidth-throttle[0.1].
    - bandwidth-throttle/bandwidth-throttle 0.1 requires bandwidth-throttle/token-bucket ^0.3 -> satisfiable by bandwidth-throttle/token-bucket[0.3] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

Comment: There is no point to run `composer require bandwidth-throttle/bandwidth-throttle` inside of repository cloned from https://github.com/bandwidth-throttle/bandwidth-throttle - you're trying install library inside of itself. You should run `composer require bandwidth-throttle/bandwidth-throttle` inside of **your** project and skip cloning step - composer will take care of installing this library.

Comment: Thanks! Getting closer, but the end remains elusive.  require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';  $throttle = new BandwidthThrottle();  returns error: PHP Fatal error:  Class 'BandwidthThrottle' not found

Comment: My bad. Forgot to use. Works now. Thanks again!